# Lost ext4 partition table

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a 2 TB disk which I use for data. Running Ubuntu 14.04 from another physical drive and Windows from a third physical drive.

On the 2 TB drive I have (or, had...) one ext4 partition filling out the entire drive.

When booted into Windows 7, and entering its disk tool, I was told that the drive had no partition table (?), giving me the options of gpt and something else, before even allowing me in to the tool. Thinking it was referring to a fourth physical drive in the machine, which did indeed not have any partitions on it, I foolishly opted for gpt, but did nothing else to the drive (didn't create any partitions, etc.).

Back in Linux, when I run gpart, only what seems to be two old (now unused) partitions are found:

```
$ sudo gpart /dev/sdc

Begin scan...
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(0mb), offset(228937mb)
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(25497mb), offset(1266234mb)
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): primary 
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): primary 
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 007(0x07)(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX)
   size: 0mb #s(1) s(468863136-468863136)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (29185/97/1)-(29185/97/1)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 007(0x07)(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX)
   size: 25497mb #s(52219903) s(2593248336-2645468238)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (161422/62/1)-(164672/199/22)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

Also, fdisk doesn't seem to see it:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[...]
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242251 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

And neither parted:

```
$ sudo parted -l
[...]
Model: ATA ST2000DM001-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

What am I missing? Is there any way I can recreate the lost partition?

Comment: Microsoft automatically creates its system reserved partition when it partitions with gpt type. So it totally overwrote drive. Never use Windows tools except on Windows partitions. You may be able to use testdisk, in MBR not gpt mode to restore old partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery AND: 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: No luck either, unfortunately. But thank you for your answer. It seems I have managed to let Windows smash my partition table beyond repair. Now looking at scalpel for recovering a few critical files that weren't on a backup yet.

Comment: The scalpel you're looking for is `testdisk`. Have a look at [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)